# Add WIN32 Console Project Template To Visual Studio Community 2017 15.5.2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, console-application, project-template

I recently installed Visual Studio Community 2017 15.5.2 version for C++ basically and I am unable to find the option of Win32 Console Application. 
I have already read many post to fix it but can't. Yes, I have installed C++ in VS. I have installed the following workloads:

1. Desktop development with C++ and
2. .NET desktop development.

I have tried to install packages through VS command prompt but it didn't fix my issue. I have tried reinstalling it and repairing it but didn't find anything. I tried to find it in `File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> Windows Desktop -> Windows Desktop Wizard -> ...` but there was no option.

I want to develop simple games in C++ so i need Win32 console application option in VS. I have installed similar packages in the VS installer but it didn't help!
I have looked for it in many options but didn't got what i wanted! I have also read many posts and forums to fix it but cannot. I almost tried everything they said in those forums!

If someone knows the solution please explain it briefly and tell me which packages to install or what to do?

Also tell me possible reasons for the cause so i can fix it on my own. And if not possible tell me an alternative to it.

Answer (score 0):

seems that your not alone. The problem is know well, and already asked in Microsoft forum.
From their side they say not change has been apply in last updates, just few  re-implement.
You may see same question here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/93159/cant-find-win32-console-application-for-new-projec.html

In that case, what i would suggest you, is to install VS 2015 that still working well.
Good luck body.

Comment: yes, i have already gone through that but didn't found any good there!

Comment: What's your say should i download VS 2015 ?